Open a tab, Switch between tabs, close tab on browser not working on Playwright Typescript
I'm opening a tab (t1) using beforeEach, from that I'm opening another tab (t2). Now, I want to perform some actions on (t2) and switch to (t1). And then, close a (t2) tab.
  test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
   await page.goto(BASE_URL + "/t1");
  });


test("switch between tabs", async ({ context }) => {

  const page = await context.newPage();

  const [newtab] = await Promise.all([
    context.waitForEvent('page'),    
    await page.goto(BASE_URL + "/t2"),
    await page.getByTestId('id_here').click(),
    await page.getByTestId('id1_here').fill('test')
 ])
 //come back to tab (t1)
 //perform actions on tab (t1)
 //close tab (t2)

});


Don't forget to ask a question. Where are you stuck in your attempt, exactly? By "window" do you really mean "page"/"tab"? If so, page is w1 and newtab is w2, so you're already good. Sharing a page under automation makes everything runnable, reproducible and concrete, so you can be sure the help you're getting is actually pertinent to your use case. Thanks.

@ggorlen I updated the question, please check. I want to perform actions between tabs of a same window.

Thanks for the attention, but the post seems basically the same as before other than the tab/window fix (no question, no page under test, no context, and the code already opens two tabs, presumably successfully),  so my above comment and closure stands. I don't see how I can offer any further commentary here without clarification.

You can use context.pages() to keep track of the open windows within the test context. This will follow even the window opened during your beforeEach.
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
   await page.goto(BASE_URL + "/w1");
});

test('Foo', async ({ context }) => {
  const w2 = await context.newPage();
  const w1 = context.pages()[0]; // assumes that the first page opened always occupies the first position in the array
  // alternatively...
  const w1Alt = context.pages().find(x => x.url() === BASE_URL + "/w1")
});

Alternatively, you could keep track of the w1 window by assigning the page from your beforeEach to a variable.
let w1: Page;

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  w1 = page;
  await w1.goto(BASE_URL + "/w1");
});

test('Foo', async ({ context }) => {
  const w2 = await context.newPage();
  await w2.goto(BASE_URL + "/w2");
  // use w1 and w2 to reference each page
  await expect(w1).toHaveURL(BASE_URL + "/w1");
  await expect(w2).toHaveURL(BASE_URL + "/w2");
});


I want to perform above actions between tabs of a same page. Can you update your answer based on that?

What above actions? I can't see any additional information provided.
